# Washing clothing with sand .. how?

Tags: mourning-aveilus, washing-clothes

[Rambam Hilchos Avel 6 (13)](http://www.chabad.org/dailystudy/rambam_cdo/jewish/1-Chapter-a-Day.htm) refers to washing with sand:

> ומכבס כסותו במים אבל לא בנתר ולא בחול
>
> He may wash his clothes in water, but not with soap or using sand.

Is there an explanation of the cleaning power of sand and how was it used?

Comment: Probably as an abrasive?

Comment: @DoubleAA Dry or with water?

Comment: Not sure. You may have better luck asking on [History.se] for info about historical laundering methods.

Comment: Thank you - posted https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/40081/washing-with-sand-how

Comment: Is this on topic? It sounds like a science or laundering question.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok If you get a good answer to your question, please remember to post it here for our benefit!

Comment: As others already pointed out it's an abrasive it and it was used as a whitening agent, see Rashi (Taanit 13a -which is Rambam's source- s.v. be'neter) and Tos. (Shab. 90a s.v. burit).

Comment: @Oliver That could be developed into an answer!

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Was debating if it should be but wasn't sure if the OP was specifically asking about the method "how it was used" or "how", i.e. for what purpose.

Comment: @Oliver Well, er.., I'm the OP. The purpose is cleaning but I was interested in "how it was used" and how effective it is.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Ha - I wasn't paying attention. Do I just c&p the comment as an answer? (I'm still new at this)

Comment: @Oliver You need to reference and quote your sources either in translation or original and translation. For gemoro you can use http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas  or Sefaria. Make an attempt; I will try to edit it if needed. See https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1758/mi-yodeya-referencer-a-syntax-for-linking-to-sources too.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the [parallel thread on History.SE](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/40083/25780), sand is an abrasive. I’ll let them do the talking for me:

> Sand is an ["abrasive"](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/abrasive). As such, it is good for dislodging/removing dirt, etc. trapped in clothes.
>
> But after you do this, you have to wash out the sand.
>
> Soap does a similar job in a different way (using "chemical," rather than "mechanical" means).